# on_ready not triggered in cog file discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I have this code:

```
class Test(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("TEST")

    @app_commands.command(name="setup", description="setup")
    async def setup(self, interaction):
        await interaction.response.send_message("test")


async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(Test(bot))
```

The issue is that when the cog is loaded it doesn't print "TEST" and the code in the on_ready doesn't seem to have triggered.

I don't get any errors in output and I don't think the on_ready is triggered however `async def on_message(self, message)` works just fine. What could be the issue?

This is what the main.py looks like:

```
    import os
    import discord
    from discord.ext import commands
    
    intents = discord.Intents.all()
    intents.members = True
    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)
    
    
    async def load():
        print("Loading cogs:")
        for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"):
            if filename.endswith(".py"):
                print(filename)
                await bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
    
    
    @bot.event
    async def on_ready():
        print(f'Logged in as {bot.user.name}')
        await load()
    
    
    @bot.command()
    async def sync(ctx):
        if ctx.author.id == MY_USER_ID:
            b = await bot.tree.sync()
            await ctx.send("Currently synced " + str(len(b)) + " commands!")
            print("Sync command was issued, synced " + str(len(b)) + " commands!")
        else:
            await ctx.send('You must be me to use this command!')
    
    
    @bot.command()
    async def reload(ctx):
        if ctx.author.id == MY_USER_ID:
            print("RELOADING SELECTED COGS:")
            await ctx.send("Succesfully reloaded these cogs:")
            for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"):
                if filename.endswith(".py"):
                    await ctx.send(filename)
                    await bot.reload_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
        else:
            await ctx.send('You must be me to use this command!')
    
    
    with open('token.txt', 'r') as file:
        bot_token = file.read().strip()
    
    bot.run(bot_token)
```

Comment: For me it works, when I add your cog into the cog folder of my bot.. So I guess the error is "outside" of your provided code? How does your main file look like?

Comment: I edited the post to include my full main.py code

Comment: Is your `on_ready` event of the `main.py` module being triggered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your cog is being loaded after the `on_ready` event is fired. I recommend you load your cogs before even starting the bot:

```py
import asyncio


async def main():
    async with bot:
        print("Loading cogs:")
        for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"):
            if filename.endswith(".py"):
                print(filename)
                await bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
        await bot.start(bot_token)

asyncio.run(main())
```

By starting your bot this way, you can delete the `load()` function and also remove it from the `on_ready` event.